# Net::SFTP not connect using curve25519-sha256 algorithm

Tags: ruby, sftp

I am using net-sftp gem to connect sftp server which is using curve25519-sha256 algorithm. I am getting errror my client does not support this algorithm. I have read issue section and find a lot of discussion on it, tried few method but still I can't get it working. Following is my code

```
require 'net/sftp'
Net::SSH::Transport::Algorithms::DEFAULT_ALGORITHMS[:kex].unshift("curve25519-sha256@libssh.org")
Net::SFTP.start('ip_address_of_site', 'password', { password: 'password', append_all_supported_algorithms: true, verify_host_key: :never, verbose: :debug}, verify_host_key: :never) do |sftp|
  ssh.sftp.connect do |sftp|
    puts sftp.inspect
  end
end
```

I am getting following error

```
net-ssh-6.1.0/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb:407:in `negotiate': could not settle on kex algorithm (Net
::SSH::Exception)
Server kex preferences: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
Client kex preferences: ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,d
iffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

When I connect it using any mac software it is working fine, so no issue in my password.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot trials I found following is solution for it. May be it will help someone doing same thing.

Add gem in your Gemfile

```
gem 'x25519'
```

now in your script add following line

```
require 'x25519'
```

This will do trick and connect using that algorithm. But this still work on intel processors not on Mac M1 processor.

In the [net-ssh lib](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/v6.1/lib/net/ssh/transport/algorithms.rb), we can find the following code:

```
if Net::SSH::Authentication::ED25519Loader::LOADED
  DEFAULT_ALGORITHMS[:host_key].unshift(
    'ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com',
    'ssh-ed25519'
  )
end

if Net::SSH::Transport::Kex::Curve25519Sha256Loader::LOADED
  DEFAULT_ALGORITHMS[:kex].unshift(
    'curve25519-sha256',
    'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org'
  )
end
```

Which is loading those two gems (x25519, ed25519) if they are installed. That's why, installing and loading the gem solves the issue.

Comment: But in another gem if they are requirement they should auto load and there should be no requirement to load these gem individual in Gemfile. But this is long time old questions my solution worked for the guy who need help. But I am sure now it has been changed and hope M1 should be working too.